# Change URL basename

Tags: php, javascript, url

I'm using AJAX to display a transition between pages and I'd like to change the URL basename when the user clicks on a link. I'm using PHP to be able to use URLs like `mydomain.com/mypage`, so I'd like to be able to change "mypage" to something else like "mysecondpage". How may I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), but it is firefox-only. The standard way to do it is by using different hashes (e.g. `mydomain.com/#mypage` --> `mydomain.com/#mysecondpage`). This can be done simply by changing `window.location.hash`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you use a hash #likethis.